# How to run more than one executable (*.exe) at the same time (parallel) in python?

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-processing

I need to run different `*.exe` files in parallel in `python` 2.7. These `*.exe` files were created using the `C++` language. Also, I need that the cmd window opens for each `*.exe` file called.

I've already tried something of multiprocessing library, but it didn't work. Anything happened and the PC crashed...

```
import os
import subprocess

cwd = os.getcwd()

cmd_MakeBackgroundImage = cwd+"\\MakeBackgroundImage.exe"
cmd_SFVTest = cwd + "\\SFVTest.exe"
cmd_Wavelet_x = cwd + "\\Wavelet_x.exe"
cmd_Dataform_x = cwd + "\\Dataform_x.exe"
cmd_Wavelet_y = cwd + "\\Wavelet_y.exe"
cmd_Dataform_y = cwd + "\\Dataform_y.exe"

process_1 = os.system(cmd_MakeBackgroundImage)

process_2 = os.system(cmd_SFVTest)

#I need to run "cmd_Wavelet_x" at the same time of "cmd_Wavelet_y"
#So I need to parallelize process_3 and process_4
process_3 = os.system(cmd_Wavelet_x)

process_4 = os.system(cmd_Wavelet_y)

#I need to run "cmd_Dataform_x" at the same time of "cmd_Dataform_y"
#So I need to parallelize process_5 and process_6
process_5 = os.system(cmd_Dataform_x)

process_6 = os.system(cmd_Dataform_y)
```

I have an intermediate knowledge of python and I don't know anything about parallelization in Python.

> The code that I described does exactly that I need but in a sequential
>   way. The parallelization that I described will decrease the code
>   runtime in about 1h.

It is very important that the cmd window opens for each `*.exe`, because these cmd windows indicate the status of the code running...

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Update<\b>: In Python 2.7, you can do:

`pip install futures`

to get all the features in concurrent.futures

Still using Python 2.7? DoD is 2020. If you move to 3.2+ you can easily use `concurrent.futures` with almost the same code.

```
import concurrent.futures
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()

cmd_MakeBackgroundImage = cwd+"\\MakeBackgroundImage.exe"
cmd_SFVTest = cwd + "\\SFVTest.exe"
cmd_Wavelet_x = cwd + "\\Wavelet_x.exe"
cmd_Dataform_x = cwd + "\\Dataform_x.exe"
cmd_Wavelet_y = cwd + "\\Wavelet_y.exe"
cmd_Dataform_y = cwd + "\\Dataform_y.exe"

# add cmds to be ran concurrently
programs = [cmd_SFVTest, cmd_Wavelet_x, cmd_Dataform_x, cmd_Wavelet_y, cmd_Dataform_y]

# you can use either Process or Thread depends on your needs

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(os.system, programs)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi it works fine. However I need to run `MakeBackgroundImage.exe` and `SFVTest.exe` using `os.system` before the other codes. When I use `concurrent.futures` after `os.system` all the exe files previously executed are executed again in parallel. It is a strange bug. I am using Spyder 3.3.6.